# call a modified alert function on php if

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to call a java script function which displays a modified alert box as a warning when the user clicks an anchor link

in this case I am using `$_REQUEST['id']` as a reference to check my link if it is already clicked

PHP

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {

// how can I call my function which will display my modified alert box here? 
// is it possible?
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>   

function myFunction() {
      $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height: 300,
      width: 700,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
          "Upload": function() {

          document.forms["form1"].submit();



          $(this).dialog("close");
          },
          Cancel: function() {

          window.location.href = "uploadCSV.php";
          $(this).dialog("close");
          }
      }
      });
  }

 </script>
```

Anchor Link:

```
echo '<a name="' . $row['Id'] . '"><tr class="even pointer"><td class="a-center ">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write code this way.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['id'])) {

// how can I call my function which will display my modified alert box here? 
// is it possible?
?>
<script> myFunction(); </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thanks
Amit